# Where should data validation occur in Ruby on Rails with multiple tables at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller

I'm using RoR and was stuck by how to properly and elegantly validate data from front end. My server is only an API-based RoR app.

There are 4 tables relevant to this issue,  **identity_types** to store the type of identity, **identities** to store user identities, **users** to store password digest and other info, **levels** to store user level such as worker, manager and so on.

For the sake of neatness, I use pseudo code in YAML to describe them with common fields omitted, like id, create_at and etc.

```
identity_types:
  name:             [string,  unique]
# e.g., name = email/telephone/nickname and etc.

identities:
  content:          [string,  unique]
  user_id:          [integer, not_null]
  identity_type_id: [integer, not_null]
# with combined unique contraint for [user_id, identity_type_id]

users:
  password_digest:  [string]
  supervisor_id:    [integer, not_null]
  level_id:         [integer, not_null]
  banned:           [boolean]

levels:
  name:             [string,  unique]
# e.g., name = worker/manager/director and etc.
```

Respectively, I've got models of them in ActiveRecord, relevant migrations, as well as their controllers. I obey the rules of RESTful, and direct 'POST /users' to 'users#create'.

Now, here comes a question:  to create a new worker with following roles.

1. A worker's supervisor can only be a manager.
2. Content of identity can't be duplicated.

What I've done currently is to put many logic into controller, not in model.

```
# controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # params_from_fe = %i[identity_content identity_type_uuid password password_confirmation supervisor_uuid]

  def create
    # 1. check if required parameters are presented
    # 2. find_by identity_content and check if content is duplicated
    # 3. find_by supervisor_uuid and check if supervisor.level is manager
    # 4. Nothing done with password + password_confirmation, since they are processed by model layer.
    # if all checks passed:
      # user = User.create
      # user.identity.create
    # other code ...
  end
end
```

Among the checking operations above, I've got unique contraint for identity content, so the 2nd step might be left out. What about the 3rd step **to verify whether a superviosr is a manager in model layer, the ActiveRecord**?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use form objects https://typefast.blog/form-objects-rails/.

Comment: Well, the third is actually not data validation, maybe your doubts come from there. the third step is an authorization question. So for this you could use a Gem like https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan which would abstract such authorizations checks. Then it will still be the controllers job to return an appriate error response that lets the API consumer know what's up.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks, I read this article just now and saw its way to abstract some logic of code. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Roland Studer Thanks, I got to know. After reading the wiki of this library, I think it is a wonderful lib and I need to work with it. I'll have a try.